# Display SOAP service result in Android

Tags: android, exception, soap

I have a database `AndroidTestDb` with a basic table `UserTable`. I also have a .Net, SOAP-based web service `WebServiceOne`. The web service has a method  `ServiceQueryOne()` which returns a string array with the values retrieved from the table UserTable. 
The service works fine, however I am struggling with the Android retrieval of the SOAP values and displaying the values in a Android list view.

See Web Service Method:
    public class WebServiceOne : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

```
public WebServiceOne()
{
    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public string[] ServiceQueryOne()
{
    List<DataClass> dataList = new List<DataClass>(); ;
    GetData gd = new GetData();        
    string query = "SELECT Name,Surname,Password FROM UserTable";
    dataList = gd.setDataList(query);
    int listCount = dataList.Capacity;
    int i = 0;
    string[] stringList = new string[listCount];
    foreach(object value in dataList)
    {
        stringList[i] = dataList[i].toString();
        i++;
    }
//returns a string 
    return stringList;
}
```

[Service returned result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sly6K.png)

```
<LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvResult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also have a web service class in my Android to handle the passing of `SOAP` objects:

```
public class WebServiceClass {
String URL = "http://localhost:54079/WebServiceOne.asmx";
String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
String METHOD_NAME;
String SOAP_ACTION;

SoapObject request;

public SoapObject WebServiceMethodOne() {
    METHOD_NAME = "ServiceQueryOne";
    SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ServiceQueryOne";
    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    try {
        HttpTransportSE androiHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androiHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        request = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return request;
}
```

In my main activity I declare the list view and a search button with an `onClick` listener that (should) populate the list.

Search button onClickListener:

```
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            OnSearchButtonClick();
        }
    });
```

OnSearchButtonClick method:

```
public void OnSearchButtonClick(){
    SoapObject serviceData = soapService.WebServiceMethodOne();
    String getData = serviceData.getPropertyAsString(0);
    resultListView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    dataAdapter.add(getData);  
    }
```

In my `OnCreate` method I set my web service class and I link the list view object. The above `DataAdapter` is declared before onCreate method:

```
soapService = new WebServiceClass();
resultListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvResult);
```

The Result is an exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.csiwele.testwebapp_one, PID: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=at java.util.Vector.arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

The exception is thrown on the OnSearchButtonClick method:

```
String getData = serviceData.getPropertyAsString(0);
```

Although I am still trying to fix this exception I am not sure if this alone will address the issue of actually displaying the SOAP object's data in the list view. I am still new to the concept of passing SOAP objects to Android applications and while I am trying to further my understanding I feel it would help to get assistance on the particular issue at hand I currently face. Please have a look at what I have provided and advise on how I could make this code operational.